# PySpark most eluqent way to self join multiple times and change column names

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I have an pyspark Dataframe taken from an SQL server of this schema

| StationId | Year | Month | PRCP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 1900 | 5 | 14 |
| id1 | 1900 | 5 | 14 |
| id2 | 1901 | 5 | 15 |
| id2 | 1901 | 5 | 15 |

and i would like to self join a pyspark dataframe with itself in a way that a station with the same id will contain the PRCP value of its previous year.

If we look at our example i would want the following result

| StationId | Year | Month | PRCP | prev_PRCP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 1900 | 5 | 14 | null |
| id1 | 1900 | 5 | 14 | null |
| id2 | 1901 | 5 | 15 | 14 |
| id2 | 1901 | 5 | 15 | 14 |

I've tried reading the query from the SQL table but kept getting a parsing error
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: "\nmismatched input '.' expecting

How can i do this with pyspark?
Thanks in advance to all helpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(prcp) over (partition by station_id, month order by year) as prev_prcp
from t;
```

Comment: Is there such a thing in a pyspark dataframe?

Comment: @OfekGlick . . . The question is tagged SQL and this provides a SQL solution.  And the answer to your question is that PySpark does support `lag()` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag).